# Quadratic approximation of L1 regularized cost function

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent, regularization

I'm reading the Deep Learning book of Goodfellow, but I fail to see why minimization of (7.22) gives (7.23). I tried to compute the gradient w.r.t. the $w_{i}$ and set this to zero, but it doesn't give me (7.23).

[image: Figure]

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The analysis becomes a little bit hairy because of the discontinuous derivative of the L1 penalty.  There may be a better way of phrasing the argument, but here's something.

Taking the derivative of $|w_i|$ gives $\operatorname{sgn}(w_i)$, unless $w_i=0$ which we will take as a special case.
In the main case, when $w_i\neq0$, taking the derivative w.r.t. $w_i$ equal to zero gives:
$$\begin{align*}
H_{ii}(w_i-w_i^*) + \alpha \operatorname{sgn}(w_i) & = 0 \\
\Longrightarrow w_i &= w_i^* - \frac{\alpha \operatorname{sgn}(w_i)}{H_{ii}}.
\end{align*}$$

Now for a trick.  From the original loss formulation (7.22), it's clear that the optimum $w_i$ will have the same sign as $w_i^*$ (or is zero): otherwise, switching signs decreases the first term and doesn't change the second term inside the summation.  So we have
$$\begin{align*}
w_i &= w_i^* - \frac{\alpha \operatorname{sgn}(w_i^*)}{H_{ii}} \\
 &= \operatorname{sgn}(w_i^*) \left( |w_i^*| - \frac{\alpha}{H_{ii}} \right).
\end{align*}$$
And again, knowing that $w_i$ and $w_i^*$ must share sign, we must have that $|w_i^*|-\frac{\alpha}{H_{ii}}\geq0$.  If not, then this is not a location of zero-derivative, and we have to look to our other case.  In that case, simply $w_i=0$, and we can tack that on as a separate case here using the maximum given in the text.  (We should also confirm that $w_i=0$ is not the minimum when $|w_i^*|-\frac{\alpha}{H_{ii}}>0$, which is easy to do.)

Comment: Base on the fact that *H* is positive semidefinite, we can find that the new optimal $\omega$ is the same sign as the original one via the derivative equation.  However, I can not follow your logic. Can you elaborate on this conclusion: "From the original loss formulation...otherwise, switching signs decreases the first term and doesn't change the second term"? What are the first term and second term?

Comment: @Kuo I'm referring to eq 7.22, the expression inside the summand.  The first term involves $(w_i-w_i^*)^2 = w_i^2+(w_i^*)^2-2w_iw_i^*$; the first two terms in this expanded form are independent of the sign of $w_i$, but the last one is negative when the sign of $w_i$ and $w_i^*$ agree, negative when they disagree.  The second term, $\alpha|w_i|$ is independent of the sign.

Comment: Now I see the trick. The same sign guarantees the loss descending. This is a higher level analysis without going down to the derivative equation. @BenReiniger